# Сложные существительные и прилагательные, образованные от аббревиатур-названий

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Соответствует ли норме образование от аббревиатур-названий подобных сложных существительных и прилагательных?

*BM-щики / BMщики* (BM — английское название)

*ФСБ-шники / ФСБшники*

*ВАКовцы / ваковцы*

*РАНовский / рановский*

Если да, то подскажите правильное написание.

Comment: Кто такие ВМщики? Что за английское BM (би эм)?  Есть VM (ви эм), но это виртуальная машина, что это за VM-щики у Людмилы? Спецы по виртуальным машинам?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то это разговорное словообразование, даже окказиональное, но в газетах используется часто, видимо, начинает входить в язык, вот, например, рановский /РАНовский вижу часто, и хотя мне это не очень нравится на вид, но что поделать, если слово используется в языке, значит, оно существует, пусть и в разговорном варианте. Нормой это пока не стало, если в каком словаре и встретится, то будет с пометой "разговорное".

ФСБ-шники -написание неверное, чаще пишется эфэсбэшники или фээсбэшники (чаще) / ФСБшники. Шник- всё-таки суффикс, который пишется без дефиса. НТВ-энтэвэшник, ГАИ-гаишник, ДПС-дэпээсник, КВН-кавээнщик, квнщик, КВНщик.

ВАКовцы / ваковцы

А вот BM-щики / BMщики от английского названия следует писать VM-щики , потому что ВМщики воспримут как работники "Вечерней Москвы", там такая же аббревиатура.

https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/osobennosti-slovoobrazovatelnyh-novatsiy-v-sovremennoy-razgovornoy-rechi

Так как это неологизмы, написание ещё не нормировано,  можно писать на выбор. Только я бы всё равно выбрала норму - сотрудники НТВ, ДПС, РАН и и т.д.

Comment: VM — это виртуальная машина, что это за VM-щики? Спецы по виртуальным машинам?

Comment: Понятия не имею, их сейчас развелось... Есть ВМ - маркетинговая компания, есть компания "Бизнес Молодости", но они почему-то тоже пишут ВМ, нашла и VM. Я сочла, что автор написал русскими буквами, поэтому без дефиса, а если это латиницей, то через дефис.

Comment: Я же указал в своём вопросе: «BM — английское название». BM-щики / BMщики— работники компании BM.

Comment: Вопрос про BM остаётся открытым. Писать слитно или через дефис?

Comment: Почему открытый? Я же сказала, что если буквы на латинице, то через дефис

Comment: Только лишь потому, что можно спутать с аналогичной русской аббревиатурой на кириллице? А если нет возможности спутать?

Comment: Нет, потому что иностранные аббревиатуры воспринимаются как несклоняемые, а сложные слова с несклоняемой частью пишутся через дефис.

Answer (score 1):

Из статьи [Лексемы от аббревиатурного происхождения в современном русском языке](https://www.science-education.ru/ru/article/view?id=1467) (в ней рассказано о способах и тенденциях образования новых слов от аббревиатур).

**Отаббревиатурные образования** обычно возникают в устной разговорной речи как более экономные, а часто и более выразительные синонимы многословных наименований. Именно эти качества — краткость и экспрессивность — позволяют им не только широко распространяться в устной речи, но и проникать на страницы газет и журналов, а также в художественную литературу.

Для наименования отаббревиатурных образований в языкознании нет до сих пор единого термина. Их называют и «отаббревиатурными производными»,  и «отаббревиатурными образованиями», и «корневыми аббревиатурами», и «аббревемами». Однако, может быть, целесообразнее называть их «отаббревиатами».

Кавээнщик (КВН), кагэбэшник (КГБ), **фээсбэшник** (ФСБ);
**рановский** (*Или рановская профессура идет в универы к молодежи, или образно выражаясь — сосет лапу.*) и **РАНовский** (*...перенаправлены на госуниверситет и на РАНовские институты.*);
[ва́ковский](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/273364/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) (словарь Ефремовой), **ва́ковец**;
**вээмщик** — я бы написала так (по аналогии с [эвээмщик](https://books.google.ee/books?id=zYU7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA472&lpg=PA472&dq=%D1%8D%D0%B2%D1%8D%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=wJsVV3hmAK&sig=0xD7sG9mDy0BOmhytlCisrkVbpc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt3JX5ruPeAhXF1iwKHeonAcMQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%8D%D0%B2%D1%8D%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA&f=false), от ЭВМ).

Comment: Кто такие вээмщики? Все-таки BM (для вычислительных машин)  в русском не прижилось, в отличие от ЭВМ. Есть VM (ви эм), но это виртуальная машина, что это за VM-щики у Людмилы?

Comment: Честное слово, я не знаю — кто это / что это. Не встречался термин, ассоциации чисто интуитивные.

Comment: @М_Г Это английская аббревиатура (латинские буквы BM). Никак не может быть виртуальная машина. Может быть Brand Manager или Business Manager, например.

Comment: @grizzly Manager? Не думаю, что к названию профессии/должности добавляют суффикс -щик.

Comment: Есть ещё вот такое: **визуальный мерчандайзинг (ВМ)**. http://moda.hse.ru/vm

Comment: @М_Г Так ведь я тоже так не думаю.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Мерчандайзингщики? Остроумно, но вряд ли широко употребимо.

Comment: Не знаю-не знаю — время для _понавыдумываний,_ кажется, наступило.

Comment: Я же указал в своём вопросе: «BM — английское название». BM-щики / BMщики— работники компании BM. Никаких VM, ЭВМ...